# Validity of iterator pointing to erased item

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, erase

On [that page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/), it's said that:

> this invalidates all iterator and
>   references to elements after position
>   or first.

Does that means `position` and `first` iterators are valid after the erase?

(Obviously, I ask that because I want to delete some item in a vector during a for_each loop.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#414 `positon` and `first` should be considered invalid - the wording in the standard is unclear but as iterators and references are mentioned in one sentence, and a reference to an erased element doesn't make sense, it was "taken for granted" that erasing invalidated iterators pointing to the erased element. I'd avoid depending on the erased iterator being valid - when you erase `begin()` from a vector with one element I wouldn't take for granted that the iterator suddenly was equal to `end()`

Comment: " The standard specifically says: "Invalidates all the iterators and references after the point of the erase." This has been raised as a defect. The N3242 draft of C++0x changes this to: "Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase." – Jerry Coffin.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin So I see.  It's rather obviously a defect,
however, because the definition of not invalidating an iterator
means that it points to the same element it did previously.
Which is impossible if the element has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Often if you're trying to delete multiple items from a `vector` in a loop, using `remove_if` will give you better performance than using `erase` on each item. Consider this rather than iterate-erase.

To answer your question however, yes they're valid but be careful about incrementing the iterator before testing it for `end` again, since the erase could make your iterator now equal to `end`. EDIT: @Erik's answer indicates that it may not actually be valid, but the wording is unclear.

Comment: Performance are not (yet) an issue, and I am not enough familiar with the stl to write nice code with the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But they won't refer to the same element as they did before the `erase()`, because that element will have been erased!

Answer (score 0):

If you are erasing while iterating, consider this syntax:

```
vector<int> items = ...;

for(vector<int>::iterator it = items.begin() ; it != items.end() ; /*inline*/)
{
   if(/* should erase*/)
      it = items.erase(it);
   else
      ++it;
}
```

This works because `erase()` returns an iterator to the next element after the current one.  So, if you erased, it gets 'incremented', otherwise, you increment it like normal.  As others have noted though, this is not very efficient (since all elements after the current one are copied forward), and there are better ways.  For example, as Mark B mentioned, it may be better to use `remove_if`.

Answer (score 0):

That's what it says, but it's wrong.  According to the standard,
they are invalidated (which makes sense, since to remain valid,
they'd have to point to an element which was no longer there).

Comment: Actually, no. The standard specifically says: "Invalidates all the iterators and references *after* the point of the erase." This has been raised as a defect. The N3242 draft of C++0x changes this to: "Invalidates iterators and references *at or after* the point of the erase."

Comment: Very useful comment Jerry Coffin.